# color devex xtragrid row for the data is greater than a value

Tags: c#, colors, devexpress, xtragrid

when I tryin to color rows for a constraint value it makes because of the string value like this:

```
private void gvTerbiyedekiDispolar_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView View = sender as GridView;
        if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
        {
            string category = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["fire"]);
            if (category == "0,10")
            {
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;                   
            }               
        }
    }
```

but if I try to "color the values greater than 0.1" it give me runtime error like this code

```
 private void gvTerbiyedekiDispolar_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView View = sender as GridView;
        if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
        {
            double category = Convert.ToDouble(View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["fire"]));
            if (category > 0.10)
            {
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;                   
            }               
        }
    }
```

what should I do ?

Comment: Do you have a null value in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced NULL values to 0 with `ISNULL` and it is OK.